# Sending list of data received from api in controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send list received in var result to my view in order to display it.
I am able to get values in Controller for var result but when I want to pass those values in order to use in View I am getting error on result.ResponseObject saying System.Collection cant be converted to Base. Basically var result has a list.

But i am getting error.

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.Document]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Project.Models.Document'.

Controller:

```
public  async Task<IActionResult> GetAllSavedDocument(int id)
{
    var result = await _applicationService.GetAllSavedDocument(id);

    return HandleResult(() => View("_Alldocuments", result.ResponseObject), result.Status);

}
```

My model contains information

```
public class Document
{
  public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
  public string URI { get; set; }
  public string Author { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Based on your error message, can you post the code for your view for the `@model` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view needs to reference a list not a single object.

change `@model Document` to `@model List<Document>` or `@model IEnumerable<Document>` int the `"_Alldocuments"` view